# Interpretation of the length function $|\langle .\rangle|$ in Godel coding

Tags: logic

According to the definition of Godel coding by successive prime numbers, length function $|a|$ is interpretable for a valid number. As an instance, for $a = 72$:

$a = 2^{4}.3^{2} = \langle3,1\rangle$. Therefore, $|a|=2$.

But in case of $|\langle a\rangle|$, I've no clear idea about its semantic and why $|a| \neq |\langle a\rangle|$.

Could you explain a little bit about this length function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence coded by $x$ is not $\langle x\rangle$! $\langle x\rangle$ is the sequence with one term, "$x$". E.g. if $x=2^43^2$, then $x$ represents the sequence $\langle 3, 1\rangle$ of length $2$; but $\langle x\rangle$ is a sequence of length $1$.

Now, if "$\vert \cdot \vert $" is the "length of the sequence coded by" function, then it doesn't make sense to feed it a *sequence*. However, we often write "$\vert\sigma\vert$" for "$\vert [\sigma]\vert$" if $\sigma$ is a sequence (where "$[\sigma]$" is the Goedel number of $\sigma$). So basically, ignoring the slight abuse of notation, the point is that regardless of what $x$ is, $\langle x\rangle$ always has length $1$, but the sequence *coded* by $x$ could be much longer (and even if it only has one term, that term will not be $x$ - this isn't hard to show).